# Si uso apollo server es necesario usar express?

Tags: backend

estoy aprendiendo back-end, tenia conocimiento de Nodejs y express, pero ahora estoy queriendo utilizar apollo, mi pregunta es, si yo creo un server con apollo, puedo utilizar librerias como multer, auth0 ,morgan,fs o para usar esos middleware debo usar nodejs o express.
gracias por su tiempo